# Protons and neutrons are subatomic particles that affect the mass of an atom. What would be a heavy particle and what would be a light particle?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, atoms, subatomic

An atom consists of 3 parts: Protons, neutrons, electrons. Protons and neutrons go to the center to make up the nucleus, while the electrons go to the outside in the electron cloud. Of the three subatomic particles, there are light particles and heavy particles. Heavy charged particles are all energetic ions with a mass of one atomic mass unit or greater, such as protons, alpha particles (helium nuclei), or fission fragments. Light charged particles like electrons and positrons also lose energy by emission of Bremsstrahlung photons in the electric field of a nucleus.

Comment: This is a question?

Comment: Yes. I'm confused and I was thinking protons are heavy particles and electrons would be light, but now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many subatomic particles. Some are heavier than others. The only common ones in everyday life are neutrons, protons, and electrons. Neutrons and Protons have about the same mass, 1839 and 1836 times heavier than an electron. Other subatomic particles are heavier or lighter.

The nucleus of an atom is a particle, even though it contains protons and neutrons stuck together. The heaviest particles are the larger atomic nuclei.

H usually just has 1 proton. But some H atoms also have 1 or even 2 neutrons. He has 2 protons and 2 neutrons. Other atoms have more. The biggest has 118 protons and 175 neutrons. These are very heavy indeed compared to an electron.

At the other end of the scale, the lightest particles, such as photons have 0 mass. Neutrinos have so little mass that it hasn't been measured, though it is above 0.

Like anything else, heavy and light are relative. An electron is usually thought of as a light particle. But compared to a neutrino, it is heavy.